# How to modify the data in a column using Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, wolfram-mathematica, data-cleaning

I am working on a `Dataset` object with one column, named `Property`.

The data is given as shown in the following picture:

[image: a column of this kind of data]

Based on the range, I would like to assign a new value, and eventually replace the whole column in question. For example if the range is 500-5000, I would like to get the value 1, and for 5000-50000, I would like to give the value 2, and so on.

Comment: When you say it is a data set, do you mean as in a `Dataset`?  Do you want to replace the column, or add a new column, or just pull out the recoded column?

Comment: Yes it is a data of type Dataset. I want to replace the column with the desired values as mentioned in question. I named my whole data as "dataset"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to recode one column of a dataset by modifying the dataset.  To my knowledge, datasets are not really designed to be mutable types.  If you can accept that, here are two ways to proceed.

First, let's get some artifical data.

```
ds = Dataset[<|"x" -> RandomInteger[10], 
     "y" -> Interval[{10^#, 10^(# + 1)}]|> & /@ Range[5]]
```

Now suppose we want to recode the second column with a function `f`:

```
ds[All, {2 -> f}]
```

Note that the original dataset is unchanged.  (Usually a good thing.)
Here's an example function to try out.

```
f[x_Interval] := Log[10, x[[1, 1]]]
ds[All, {2 -> f}]
```

Now a big problem with this is that your new dataset has a column with exactly the same name but entirely different interpretation.  If this bothers you, you can instead append to the dataset with a new name.

```
Append[#, "y2" -> f[#y]] & /@ ds
```

**Edit:**

What about those dollar signs?  Unless you show us the full form of an entry, I'll have to guess.  So I'll guess that the following artificial data gets us close enough to be useful:

```
ds = Dataset[<|"x" -> RandomInteger[10], 
 "y" -> Quantity[Interval[{10^#, 10^(# + 1)}], "USDollars"]|> & /@ Range[5]]
```

This just means we need to make a small change in `f`:

```
f[Quantity[Interval[{x_, _}], _]] := Log[10, x]
```

Then we can replace or append as before:

```
ds[All, {2 -> f}]
Append[#, "y2" -> f[#y]] & /@ ds
```

Comment: But how do I remove the $ symbol while processing? My data is as shown in the question. I understood your explanation though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It helped me to obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If we have grid `stuff` with column integer `x` (starting from 1 as we are in mathematica) named "Property", the code to get the column of transformed ranges in `x` -- to what I think want you -- is below:

```
Replace[#1[[1]] & /@ stuff, x_ :> IntegerLength[x[[1, 1]]] - 2, {1}]
```

It takes all the ranges in the specified column, and subtracts 2 from the length of the lower part of the range to give you your result.

For example, if we take your sample ranges:

```
stuff = {{$Interval[{500, 50000}], things, things},
  {$Interval[{5000, 5000000}], things, things}}
```

And run it through our `Replace`:

```
Replace[#1[[1]] & /@ stuff, x_ :> IntegerLength[x[[1, 1]]] - 2, {1}]
```

We get an `Out:` of:

```
{1, 2}
```

You can then easily modify the `Replace` above to give you the transformed column in situ of `stuff`.

Comment: x[[1,_]] gets the list out of $Interval (e.g., {5000, 5000000}). x[[1,1]] gets the first part of that list (i.e., the lower limit of the range). IntegerLength gets the number of digits in such an integer.

Comment: Hi so I tried to replace the name stuff with the column by writing dataset[All,"Property"] and then I see that it is accessing the first row and first column of my table. Could you help me to correct this.

Comment: I am not familiar with Dataset. What I have above works on a list of lists. Can you interface with Dataset like it is a list of lists? Can you give me a sample of the result of dataset[All, "Property"]?

Comment: I can explain it in this way. If you have the name of your whole dataset as "Hello" and it contains one column with name "Property" on writing Hello[All,"Property"] gives you the data containing in the column "Property" as output.

Comment: Is the result a List? Like {$Interval[{500, 50000}], ...}?

Comment: I do not think so, I get the output in a tabular form. I used the command Head[Hello[All,"Property"]] to find the type and the output was 'Dataset'.

Comment: Try Normal[Hello[[All,"Property"]]]

Comment: More clearly try Normal[<name of `Dataset`>][[All, "Property"]]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148941/discussion-between-heart94-and-llvmastproject).